# How to append client names to listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a listbox that, when server accepts a connection, should display the names of the clients. The **server** code is as follows:

```
class GUI2(GUI): #server GUI

    def __init__(self):

        self.clientlist = tk.Listbox(self.clientframe) #listbox  that should display client names
        self.clientlist.pack(expand = 1)

        self.s = INITSERVER()
    
        self.process = Process(target = self.s.startChat) #prevents the GUI from freezing due to server running

        self.process.start()

class INITSERVER(GUI2): 

      def startChat(self): #starts the server
   
          print("server is working on " + self.SERVER)
    
          self.server.listen(30) #sets max number to only 30 clients

          while True:
            
                self.conn, self.addr = self.server.accept()
            
                self.name = self.conn.recv(1024).decode(self.FORMAT)

                self.clientlist.insert("end", self.name) #append client names to listbox supposedly

                print(f"Name is :{self.name}")
```

The **client** code is as follows:

```
class INITCLIENT(GUI3): #GUI3 is client GUI; calls INITCLIENT when done packing

    def __init__(self):

        self.PORT = 5000
        self.SERVER = "" #left blank for this post; contains the server's exact address
        self.ADDRESS = (self.SERVER, self.PORT)
        self.FORMAT = "utf-8"

        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                   socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.client.connect(self.ADDRESS)

        self.name = g.entergname.get() # g = GUI() i.e. root window; entergname is Entry widget where client inputs their names

        self.client.send(self.name.encode(self.FORMAT)) #sends inputted names to INITSERVER to display in listbox.... supposedly
```

Through VS Code, I run the server first, then join the server using another terminal; the problem happens next.

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "f:\project\mainmenu.py", line 341, in startChat
    self.clientlist.insert("end", self.name) #append client names to listbox
AttributeError: 'INITSERVER' object has no attribute 'clientlist'`
```

I tried replacing `self.clientlist.insert` to `super().clientlist.insert` but the same error pops up with `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'clientlist'

Any help in fixing the error, or in pointing me to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: So after countless trial and error, I think the error is caused by the duplicate/child processes not knowing what is `self.clientlist` because they don't know that self (i.e. INITSERVER) is a child of GUI2; Process doesn't duplicate the parent attributes, only the ones within the function of Startchat().

Is there a way to restructure the code so that the clients' names can be displayed through listbox? Or is what I'm doing not compatible with Python and I have to display it in some other way?

Comment: You cannot share tkinter widget across processes, use thread instead.  Also it is strange that `INITSERVER` inherits from `GUI2` which creates an instance of `INITSERVER` inside itself.

Comment: @acw1668 I switched it back to Threading but it still yields the same error: `AttributeError: 'INITSERVER' object has no attribute 'clientlist'. Did you mean: 'clients'?`

Also, yes I made INITSERVER inherit from GUI2 so that the former can access `self.client` listbox and append the client names to it. Though evidently, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you print *something* to the console inside `GUI2.__init__()`, did you see that *something* when creating instance of `INITSERVER`?  If not, then `self.clientlist` will not be defined in the instance. Note that it ie better to print something before and after creating the instance.

Comment: @acw1668 Actually in my trials and errors, I did print the client names to test if the server actually works; it did print. The server works; it only errors when I try to insert these names to the listbox.

This project requires me to display these names in a widget, preferably listbox; is there any way how? Because if not, then either I have to display these names in some other way or I have to chalk it up as a tkinter limitation. Maybe other GUI framework like PyQt5 could remedy this.

Comment: I mean to print something before and after the line `self.s = INITSERVER()`, for example "before init" and "after init" correspondingly.  If you see only one set of those messages, then  `self.clientlist` will not be defined in instance of `INITSERVER`.

Comment: @acw1668 It did print before and after the line `self.s = INITSERVER()`. The code is as follows:

Comment: @acw1668 Ignore unfinished comment above. It printed on console before and after `self.s = INITSERVER()`. So I tried inserting into listbox inside INITSERVER __init__ function; it didn't work. You were right, it wasn't being defined. Is there a remedy for this?

I've tried putting the code from INITSERVER to GUI2 but it didn't work because pickle won't work with Tkinter objects; that was multiprocessing. Maybe it'll work this time with Thread.

Comment: @acw1668 FINALLY, it worked. I did what I said and it worked; all I had to do was use Thread instead of Process. Thanks for giving me tips and guiding me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @acw1668 I was guided to the answer: I just needed to remove the INITSERVER class and move all of its functions and attributes to GUI2 class, then use Threading instead of Process to target startChat to bypass Tkinter pickle errors. The new code is as follows:

```
class GUI2(GUI): #server GUI

    def __init__(self):

        self.clientlist = tk.Listbox(self.clientframe) #listbox  that should display client names
        self.clientlist.pack(expand = 1)


        self.thread = Thread(target = self.startChat) #prevents the GUI from freezing due to server running

        self.thread.start()

    def startChat(self):

        if (self.checksignal == 0): #custom-made stop signal for stopping the thread
   
            print("server is working on " + self.SERVER)
    
            self.server.listen(30)

            while True:
            
                self.conn, self.addr = self.server.accept()
           
                self.name = self.conn.recv(1024).decode(self.FORMAT)

                self.clientlist.insert("end", self.name) #append client names to listbox


        else:

            return
```